# C# driver for MongoDb: how to use limit+count?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

From MongoDb documentation: "*On a query using skip() and limit(), count ignores these parameters by default.  Use count(true) to have it consider the skip and limit values in the calculation.*" That's exactly what I need to count resulted elements for the specific query until it's over defined limit like 1000, but I do not see any way to do it in c# driver. Count of IMongoCollection and SetCount of IMongoCursor are both parameter-less. Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`Size`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.4/html/82ca8aa5-cf7b-6f85-c08d-ecacabfa0b03.htm) method instead of `Count`, as that honors Skip and Limit.

```
Console.WriteLine(collection.Find(query).SetSkip(0).SetLimit(1).Size());
```

Answer (score 17):

Looks like it is now

```
Console.WriteLine(collection
    .Find(filter)
    .Skip(30)
    .Limit(30)
    .Count());
```