# Selecting elements within a range in mongo DB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Current Code

```
List<UserDetails> query = UserDetailcollection.AsQueryable<UserDetails>().Where<TempleListDetails>(tld => tld.Name!= "x").ToList();
MongoCursor<TempleListDetails> temples  = UserDetailcollection.FindAll().SetLimit(N);
```

Problem

Using this code I am able to bring top N results, but I want to retrieve results from 5th column to 10th column

How will i be able to get that?

I tried using `.find(query)` but I am not able to query using Rownum

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slice with Projection with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858247/slice-with-projection-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry. Wrong duplicate. You mean from the results not an embedded array. This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966226/c-sharp-driver-for-mongodb-how-to-use-limitcount